# When is it okay to say 在……的时候 instead of 当……的时候？

Tags: grammar, usage, sentence-structure

I always see 在……时/的时候，but whenever I try to use this phrase, natives tell me to say 当……时/的时候 instead. Examples of 在……时/的时候 from natives：

> 如果我`在`讲话`的时候`用到这些词的话……
>
> `在`阅读某些文章`的时候`……
>
> 我觉得`在`我给你发了修改的文章`时`说会更好一点。
>
> `在`上班`时`……
>
> `在`课堂`时`……

我自己造句的：

> 当我说中文时……（在我说中文时……？）
>
> 当他去中国旅行时……（在他去中国旅行时……？）
>
> 当下雨时我用雨伞。（在下雨时我用雨伞 ？）

Just wondering if anyone can shed some light on this. When is it more preferable to use one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

在 is "at...something is happening"; 当 is "when...something is happening". Sometimes they are interchangeable, but not always.

"在我"讲话的时候, ... = "当我"讲话的时候, ... The two sentences are interchangeable.

But 如果"在我"讲话的时候... (If at the time I am talking, ...) and 如果"当我"讲话的时候... (If when I am talking, ...) are not, because "if" conflicts with "when" - "if" indicates uncertain about something, but "when" indicates certainty.

**Usual patterns of 在 and 当:**

- 我觉得**在**我给你发了修改的文章**後**说会更好一点。[Pattern: 在...(之)後]
- 我觉得**当**我给你发了修改的文章**时**说会更好一点。[Pattern: 当...(之)时]

**Comments on the example sentences:**

- 当我**说**中文**时**, 很搞笑. (When I speak Chinese, it sounds funny.)
- 在我说中文时…… does not match the usual pattern 在...之前/後/間. But, 在我演說时…… = 当我演說时……, because 演說时 is a complete phrase by itself, that does not fall within the usual patterns.
- 当他去中国旅行时…… = 在他去中国旅行时…… Same as above, 旅行时 is a complete phrase by itself.
- 当下雨时我用雨伞。= 在下雨时我用雨伞。下雨时 is a complete phrase by itself.

Comment: May I ask for some clarification regarding: ”演說时 is a complete phrase by itself“ And by extension, if I want to use 在……时，then it must be a complete phrase by itself?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean.  But look at the pattern - 演說, 旅行, and 下雨 all are actions (verb) that differ from 中文, a noun, 中文时 can't be a standalone phrase.